# if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i need help with my bot Discord.js, i have

```
    if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);
                                        ^
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_NAME]: MessageEmbed field names must be non-empty strings.
    at Util.verifyString (/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Util.js:427:41)
    at MessageEmbed.normalizeField (/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:554:18)
    at /node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:576:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MessageEmbed.normalizeFields (/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:575:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/MessageEmbed.js:339:42)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/index-beta.js:3445:8)
    at Query.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
    at Query._callback (/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
    at Sequence.end (/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_NAME'
}
Node.js v18.12.1
```

my code:

```
                    if (incident(message, messageguild, messagedev) == false) {
                        return
                    }
                    
                                })
                            })
                            .catch(function(err) {
                                discorderror(err,message)
                            })
                        })
                        .catch(function(err) {
                            discorderror(err,message)
                        })
                    })
                    });
                })
                }
```

i have add `, true` no work and i have see:
stackoverflow.com/questions/72555133/if-typeof-data-string-throw-new-errorerrormessage

no work for me, i need help for debug or give template last version discord.js for server verified.
THX

And maybe I got the code wrong, which is why I’m redirecting myself to you for help because I don’t know how to fix the problem anymore.

my robot has an extremely long source code and I have not yet succeeded in converting the code into this latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `.addFields("name", "value")` but:

```js
.addFields(
{name: "name", value: "value"},
{name: "name2", value: "value2"}
)
```

Comment: thank you for you help, i have error with you code.
 
my code is too long see link: pastebin.com/snBWbn1w

fast error:
```
/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/Util.js:427
    if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);
{
  [Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'
}
```

Comment: addFields({name: "name1", value: `${youroption}`})
add the `${}`